# Deleted media from ftp Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

A lot of files has been deleted by FTP (upload folder) and are still visible in the media admin page. Is there a fast way to delete them from the DB to do not show them in admin anymore. Like if they physically exist do nothing else delete in the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put below code in functions.php of your active theme. Just reload your page and check in the media section.

```
add_action('init','deleteAllImages');
function deleteAllImages()
{
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    $attachments = get_posts($args);    
    foreach ($attachments as $key => $value) {
        wp_delete_attachment($value->ID);
    }

}
```